# How to add multiple drawables to TextView?

Tags: android, textview, android-custom-view

I need to show 3 drawables on a TextView. I've tried with a custom view, and it works. But, as I'm extending of LinearLayout, I'm not able to use TextView properties, as textColor, textSize, etc directly on xml. Is possible to do that extending of TextView? Here is my code:

verified_component.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtUserName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/gray_333333"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:lines="1"
    android:maxWidth="200dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/iconVerified"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. " />

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/iconVerified"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/txtUserName"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txtUserName"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/iconOwner"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/txtUserName"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/verificado" />

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/iconOwner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/txtUserName"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iconVerified"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/iconAdmin"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/txtUserName"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/badge_owner" />

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/iconAdmin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/txtUserName"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iconOwner"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/txtUserName"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/iconModerator"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/badge_adm" />

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/iconModerator"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/txtUserName"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iconAdmin"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/txtUserName"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/badge_mod" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

VerifiedTextView.java

```
package br.com.hotmart.hifire.v2.widget;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import br.com.hotmart.hifire.R;

public class VerifiedTextView extends LinearLayout {
    View layout = null;
    TextView textViewUserName = null;
    AppCompatImageView iconVerified = null;
    AppCompatImageView iconOwner = null;
    AppCompatImageView iconAdmin = null;
    AppCompatImageView iconModerator = null;
    Context context = null;

    public VerifiedTextView(Context context) {

        super(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public VerifiedTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        this.context = context;

        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.VerifiedTextView);

        String userName = a.getString(R.styleable.VerifiedTextView_userName);
        userName = userName == null ? "" : userName;

        boolean isVerified = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.VerifiedTextView_isVerified, false);
        boolean isOwner = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.VerifiedTextView_isOwner, false);
        boolean isAdmin = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.VerifiedTextView_isAdmin, false);
        boolean isModerator = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.VerifiedTextView_isModerator, false);

        String service = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(service);

        if (li != null) {
            layout = li.inflate(R.layout.verified_component, this, true);

            textViewUserName = layout.findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);
            iconVerified = layout.findViewById(R.id.iconVerified);
            iconOwner = layout.findViewById(R.id.iconOwner);
            iconAdmin = layout.findViewById(R.id.iconAdmin);
            iconModerator = layout.findViewById(R.id.iconModerator);

            setText(userName);
            setIsVerified(isVerified);
            setIsOwner(isOwner);
            setIsAdmin(isAdmin);
            setIsModerator(isModerator);
        }
        a.recycle();
    }

    public VerifiedTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void setText(String text) {
        textViewUserName.setText(text);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void setIsVerified(boolean isVerified) {
        iconVerified.setVisibility(isVerified ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void setIsOwner(boolean isOwner) {
        iconOwner.setVisibility(isOwner ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void setIsAdmin(boolean isAdmin) {
        iconAdmin.setVisibility(isAdmin ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void setIsModerator(boolean isModerator) {
        iconModerator.setVisibility(isModerator ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    }
}
```

usage sample:

```
<com.example.VerifiedTextView
    android:id="@+id/text_name_user"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    app:userName="Lorem Ipsum"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: can you post design what actually you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can write your View's constructor to read those properties from the Attributes passed in, and then make calls to the inner text view to set those properties.

Comment: That is my plan if there's no other way haha. But I was looking for a different solution, to avoid to add every TextView property that I need to use to my custom View.